# iPhone 12 Pro debugging on device hangs

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Like many of you I received my iPhone 12 pro today in the mail! And of course the first thing I wanted to do was run it in debug on my actual device. Curious if any of you with new iPhone 12's, or iPhone 12 pro's are seeing a huge lag when trying to debug to the device. for example it takes almost 1 min to even hit the entry point in the app delegate, and about 20 seconds when given focus to a uitextview for the keyboard to show up (after the 1st time the keyboard loads, the subsequent ones are instant)

Its super crazy because the simulator is instant, all other actual devices (Xs etc) are instant (all on 14.1), but my brand new 12 pro is unworkable when debugging to it.

Any suggestions? Ive tried multiple projects, seems to do it on every one. Ive submitted a feedback as well.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the device, then delete the contents of `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` and restart Xcode.